# How can we use exists query in tandem with the search query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a scenario in Elasticsearch where my indexed docs are like this :-

```
    {"id":1,"name":"xyz", "address": "xyz123"}
    {"id":1,"name":"xyz", "address": "xyz123"}
    {"id":1,"name":"xyz", "address": "xyz123", "note": "imp"}
```

Here the requirement stress that we have to do a term match query and then provide relevance score to them which is a straight forward thing but the additional aspect here is if any doc found in search result has note field then it should be given higher relevance. How can we achieve it with DSL query? Using **exists** we can check which docs contain notes but how to integrate with **match** query in ES query. Have tried lot of ways but none worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ES 5, you could [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html) your [`exists` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) to give a higher score to documents with a `note` field. For example,

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "name": {
                        "query": "your term"
                    }
                }
            },
            "should": { 
                "exists": {
                    "field": "note",
                    "boost": 4
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With ES 2, you could try a [boosted filtered subset](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/function-score-filters.html)

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": { "name": "your term" }
            },
            "functions": [
            {
                "filter": { "exists" : { "field" : "note" }},
                "weight": 4
            }
            ],
            "score_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as I know boost doesn't work with exists. Well will try this query and will keep you inform.

Comment: Do you see documents without field note in result?

Comment: @nikoshr the environment I am working in has ES 2.3.3. Can't update the ES now as its production env. any thing with the version I have given

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for boosting query feature
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-boosting-query.html

```
{
   "query": {
      "boosting": {
         "positive": {
            <put yours original query here>           
         },
         "negative": {
            "filtered": {
               "filter": {
                  "exists": {
                     "field": "note"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "negative_boost": 4
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: the filter query will limit the result to docs which has note field. But the requirement is that the result can have docs without note field only thing being if the doc has note field then it should be given higher relevance and should appear in top results.

Comment: Indeed you are right I have misread documentation. See updated answer.